# Jasper Report Text Field gets cut

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

```
    <band height="20">
        <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="0" width="545" height="20" uuid="835e5c50-820a-48e7-aa71-b0e5fea3737f">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box bottomPadding="10">
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Justified" markup="none">
                <font fontName="Helvetica Neue" size="8.7"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["RAY ENGINEERING PRIVATE LIMITED mainly deals in products such as GENERAL CONSTRUCTION SERVICES OF HIGHWAYS, STREETS, ROADS, RAILWAYS AND AIRFIELD RUNWAYS, BRIDGES AND TUNNELS (37.32%),CONSTRUCTION SERVICES OF OTHER NON-RESIDENTIAL BUILDINGS SUCH AS EDUCATIONAL INSTITUTIONS,HOSPITALS, CLINICS INCLUDING VERTINARY CLINICS, RELIGIOUS ESTABLISHMENTS, COURTS, PRISONS, MUSEUMS AND OTHER SIMILAR BUILDINGS (16.22%),GENERAL CONSTRUCTION SERVICES OF HARBOURS, WATERWAYS, DAMS, WATER MAINS AND LINES & IRRIGATION AND OTHER WATERWORKS (12.48%)"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
```

The whole text is not getting printed . It gets cut after OTHER .
If i add more words in the end after (12.48%) it starts displaying the whole text.
This unusual issue seems to due to a bug in jasper library as i have tried every aspect to correct this.